# How does Facebook attribute a mobile app installation to a specific Facebook Mobile App Install Ad?

Tags: facebook, mobile

There are several questions on SO that touch on this, but the KEY question I need answered is this:

How does Facebook attribute an installation of a mobile app to a specific NewsFeed Mobile App Install Ad? Corollary: In the Facebook Insights dashboard, is the Mobile App Installations tab recording JUST installs derived from Mobile App Install Ads? Or is this capturing ALL installations?

It seems that the PublishInstall method is called every time the app is installed (assuming the Facebook SDK is integrated). How do I know Facebook is ONLY counting installs derived from the ad?

If anyone can source to something that would be the best, but an answer from knowledge would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: I too am wondering if making this call will cause every install to be tracked on Facebook, or if it will somehow know to only track installs that come from Facebook Mobile App Install Ads. It has been a year since you posted this question, but I still cannot find anything particularly clear. Did you ever get an answer to this question?